# How I can download a blu-ray iso of Debian with the most amount of packages possible for work offline?

Tags: debian, debian-installer

I have pretty decent bandwidth here, but soon I will need to be abroad with nothing except for a small mobile connection. So I would like to obtain the biggest possible ISO of Debian. In other words, the opposite of the netinst. Is it possible to obtain a Blu-ray like ISO of Debian with ALL the distro packages?

Even 25-50 GB ISO file, is just that I will soon only be able to use mobile data and need to do many installs and uninstalls, but I have to use the "cd" as source.

I saw there are many DVD ISOs but they are partial and i want everything in a single ISO file.

Another option I was considering instead of downloading the ISO filw, would be setup an http server on my notebook and get a full mirror of Debian, then setup the `sources.list` to obtain files from the internal virtual lan between the vm and the machine.

I think the huge ISO option is still the easier and the best for now ;)

Comment: If you're studying or working and your boss permits it, you can download packages on other machine and install them on the one without the internet connection.

Comment: I have no boss and a 500Mbit line that i could take advantage, btw this question was down voted? Probably by users that just mi-intrepreted the title. Nobody had the need of testing things into the virtual machines but at same time can't access internet for downloading distro packages? I would just like to obtain the fulliest iso possible and use that one as source.

Comment: Title edited so that the trolls around don't take it for a noob's question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You won't find a single ISO image, although you could probably build one. The closest you'll get with existing downloads is three Blu-ray disk images, which you'll need to use [`jigdo`](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/jigdo) to download; see http://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current/amd64/jigdo-bd/ for details.

Building a partial mirror is probably more sensible; you can use [`apt-mirror`](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/apt-mirror) for that.

A full mirror is overkill for your situation. It's [doable](https://www.debian.org/mirror/ftpmirror) of course, but it would take up [approximately 300GB](https://www.debian.org/mirror/size) (for sources, `all` and `amd64` packages)...

Comment: Thank you for the reply, well 300 GB for modern notabooks are not a such overkill, I can easily store them into my internal SSD :)

Comment: About the mirror, i need just the packages pre-compiled, no need of the sources no? And only amd64 architecture, can I filter what i want to download with apt-mirror ?

Comment: @user3450548 if you goal is to minimize data usage, you probably want sources—then if you need to fix something, you can apply a patch and recompile. Patches are much smaller than the binaries.

Comment: Yes, you can filter the architectures you download with `apt-mirror`. You'll need at least `amd64` and `all`, and you might as well mirror the sources because they are much smaller than the binaries.

Comment: @derobert compile every service at realtime isn't super slow? I can trade some space for speed but if i don't need sources at all i cand avoid download them, aswell of other architectures.

Comment: @user3450548 compiling everything would take a while... but compiling the one package you need to fix is pretty quick for most packages. Not to mention, if you're traveling and something doesn't work, having the source available to read can often help figure it out (given, I'm a programmer, so I can read the source). It may or may not make sense—depends on how expensive/slow that slow connection is, and how much disk space you have. You definitely don't need other binary architectures, though. Probably only amd64. Maybe, but unlikely, i386 as well.

Answer (score 3):

There is no "full" version with all ~43k applications available for download.
However, you can create your own iso containing the needed packages.
Take a look at the [Simple-CDD](https://packages.qa.debian.org/s/simple-cdd.html) package, for a tutorial, look over [here](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianCustomCD#Building_a_Custom_Debian_CD_Set).

Comment: 43.000? You mean 43,000?

Comment: @FaheemMitha well we european use `.` where you use `,` and vice versa... let's say 43k ;)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_mark